# I get a error when using from sql.js. file is not a database

Tags: javascript, vite, mbtiles, sql.js

I have a mbtiles file and I want to read that. In addition, I used sql.js v1.10.2, when I create a new Database, it won't return an error but if I want to use a prepare method it returns an error.

```js
async function (buffer: ArrayBuffer) {
   try {
      const SQL = await initSqlJs({
         locateFile: (file) => `/src/assets/sql/${file}`,
      });

      const db = new SQL.Database(new Uint8Array(buffer));

      const stmt = db.prepare(
         "SELECT tile_column FROM map WHERE zoom_level = :z AND tile_column = :x AND tile_row = :y"
      ); // --> I have an error when running this line.

   } catch (ex) {
      console.log(ex);
   }
}
```

I can create an empty database and run a raw query to create a new table but I can't create a database from mbtiles file.

when I run prepare method, get file is not a database error

Comment: You're probably going to have to show a bit more code, at least enough to constitute a [mcve].

Comment: it's my function. it's got an array buffer data from mbtiles file and used them.

Comment: It's a bit more than that, because there are `this.[...]` calls as well. Also, no need for a picture of what an ArrayBuffer is, people familiar with JS will already know that. However, _do_ update your post to also show the actual error you're seeing, and say which line(s) they occur on. And most importantly: give the official docs a (re)read, because the syntax you're showing _does not match_ the syntax that the docs say [you should use](https://github.com/sql-js/sql.js?tab=readme-ov-file#usage). You don't inject an array buffer if you already told SQLjs which file to use.

Comment: I edited my sample code. can you help me now?

Comment: you're still going to have to put the error into your post (because "I get an error" doesn't tell anyone anything) and explain _why_ you're using `new SQL.Database(new Uint8Array(buffer));` instead of `new SQL.Database();` because as I mentioned, you _already_ tell `SQL` which database it's using in your `initSqlJs`. Right now, if someone were to have to try to reproduce your problem, would your code be enough for them to do so, if they start from "nothing"? Because that isn't really the case yet: they don't even know what they should see happening.